# Split text file with multiple record types in SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a text file that I need to import into SQL database and split to columns. The file layout is as follows:

```
AL12345... (Header row)
12...
30...
70...
EL.XXXX (Trailer row which contains also the number of records in the block)
AL23456... (Header row)
12...
30...
70...
EL.XXXX (Trailer row which contains also the number of records in the block)
AL34567... (Header row)
12...
30...
EL.XXXX (Trailer row which contains also the number of records in the block)
```

The number of blocks (from header to trailer) are one or more. When there is only one block I don't have problems importing and manipulating data. The problem arises when there is more than one block.

What should I do? Split the file if it contains more than one block and than import each file separately? If yes, how would I split the file?

Thank you!

Comment: how can you identify header, detail and footer rows? Can you do it by column count? It would be a lot easier if you pasted a better example of your source. Is there information in the header (like account or something) that you need to get into the details?

Answer (score 0):

I would read the file using the script task.
Ignore rows that begin with AL. Or EL. If the first column is numeric you should be good.